Only first document is returned from firestore querysnapshot flutter
I am querying my collection upon which I would want to return all the documents which meet inclusion criteria.
my problem: only the first document (the first in terms of time of uploading) can be returned by the future builder
Here is my code
Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    var value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('seller')
        .where('typeOfItem', isEqualTo: 'Kuku broiler')
        .where('timeAdded',
            isGreaterThan: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)))
        .get();

    print('docsnapshot${value.docs.first.data()}');

    return value.docs as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }


I can view the contents of the first document by print debug
the snippet return value.docs as Map<String, dynamic>; just returns 'an instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
when I try to return return value.docs.first.data(); only the first document is returned and nothing else
Please help wherever you can
I am waiting

Maybe you could iterate the contents of value.docs instead of explicitly taking only the first one with value.docs.first.  There is an example in the documentation:
for (var docSnapshot in value.docs) {
  print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()}');
}


Lots of thanks good people. Let me try the solution and will be back with the feedback. Best
